# How to catch only "visible" keys from KeyEvent in Java?

Tags: java, keyboard, key, keyevent

I have a KeyEvent object and i only want to process it if the key is a visible one. With visible i mean like one of these characters `` abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy1234567890^°!"§$%&/()=?`@+#*',.-;:_" ``
I do not want to process SPACE, ESC, BACKSPACE, DEL...

What i'm calling right now is `e.isActionKey()` and if it is, i don't process it. But that includes only a few keys like PAGE_UP, PAGE_DOWN.

What is the best way to filter out all the keys that i don't want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i basically already gave the answer :)

`` KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                String validString = "^°1!2\"§3$4%5&6/7{(8[)9]=0}?ß\\`´q@we€rtzuiopü*+~asdfghjklöä'#<>yxcvbnmµ;,:._-";
                if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED && validString.indexOf(String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar()).toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                    if (CardPanelView.this.cardLayout.getCurrentCard() == tabbedPane) {
                        CardPanelView.this.controller.callSetSearchText(Character.toString(e.getKeyChar()));
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }); ``